# Cache Problem in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I have a sample application with three steps as below

Enter user details -> Personal details -> Finished

When I click on a link it will invoke my vaadin application. The problem is once my three step process is finished and when I tried to again click on the my vaadin link it still shows the final wizard page 'Finished'

(Browser cache needs to be cleared or browser needs to be restarted if I want to see again first page i.e. Enter user details wizard page)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Vaadin keeps the session in memory, your application is not reset until it sees a new browser session (i.e. cache cleared or browser restarted). One more way to clear the session during development is to att ?restartApplication to your application's URL. This will also clear the application state.

So with this in mind it is clear that if you like the Vaadin application state to be reset during normal usage of it, you have to programmatically make sure the internal logic works in a way that does this. E.g. call a self-defined reset() method for your first view.

Make sure you don't confuse this session based state of an application, with a page-state which resets an applicaton every time you press reload or open a link again without a new browser session being created.

Section in Book of Vaadin about this: http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/architecture.server-side.html

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your reply. Can you post any code example to clear the vaadin cache which would be more helpful to me

Comment: Well, if you like to end the application state programmatically just call yourApplication.close(). This will end the session and restart application. However, I'd prefer to just reset the form data by setting input values to null or whatever the default values are.

Comment: Or at least consider setting values back to defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Just append `?restartApplication` parameter in your URL when calling your application in browser. 
for example,
if you are calling your application as `localhost:8080/myvaadinapp/` ,
then try calling as `localhost:8080/myvaadinapp/?restartApplication`.

It tells Vaadin Servlet to create new instance of Application on loading the page.